Excel Sortby formula on alpha numerics e.g. A1 to A100 to return 4 rows of associated data
I have used this formula to sort the column A1 to A100 so that A
=SORTBY(A1:A206,COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1:A206)),1,ROW(INDIRECT(A1:A206)),1)
thanks to one of your posts: Advanced sorting of alphanumeric data
However, how do I get this to work across four columns of data to retain the sort order of the other columns please?
Copy of sample results in link, thanks
Sample data 

Welcome Jane! Can you please edit the title of your question to make it more readable?  Thanks, and again, welcome!

Thank you where do I find the edit option please?

@JaneM Click on this link to edit your question.

It would be helpful to post a snippet of your data and a mocked up version of what you want the result to be.

I suggest you look at examples of the SORTBY() function. If you hadn't realized, your formula already has two sort by criteria, just add the other 3 in there (probably before your 2 existing criteria).

Thanks but I'm unsure where/how the other 3 need to be put.

So, I can sort A1-A100 in column 1 fine but the data consists of e.g. A1 then 3 rows of data going across, I'm looking to sort all 4 rows together eg. on one row there is the alpha numeric A1, then in column 2 on row 1 a number, then in column 3 a number, then in column 4 a number all on one row.  Are you able to provide an example of how/where the other 3 go in the existing forumla I am using please?

Thanks I've got the answer now.  The correct formula is: =SORTBY(A1:D206,COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1:A206)),1,ROW(INDIRECT(A1:A206)),1)  which will sort data alpha numeric and also return 4 rows of data.
